# Is choosing $1$ as a public exponent valid in RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, keys, public-key

I know it will not encrypt anything. But is $1$ valid as a public exponent in an RSA public key?

Comment: Are you talking about the public key or the public exponent?

Comment: The public exponent. Or choosing e to gcd(e, m) = 1.

Comment: Yes you can, the math will still check out, but you will not get any security. There was even a software that did this by accident because developers didn't know what the public exponent was supposed to be.

Comment: @MechMK1 Thank you very much!

Comment: Piece of trivia: actual deployed code, by people who really ought to know better, actually used 1 as public exponent https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/5dd304276ba5745ec21fc1e6686a0b28da29e6fc#commitcomment-3525158; and someone actually tried to use a misunderstood Thomas Pornin answer to justify it https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2339/1898

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: it is a matter of conventions and context that $e=1$ is allowed or not.

Definitions of RSA vary:

- The [original RSA article](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf) asks to first choose the private exponent $d$ as « a large, random integer which is relatively prime to $(p−1)\cdot(q−1)$ », then to compute $e$ as « the “multiplicative inverse” of $d$, modulo $(p−1)\cdot(q−1)$ ». This makes it extremely improbable that $e=1$, but allows it. Later descriptions of RSA tend to choose $e$ first.
- [PKCS#1 v1.5 / RFC 2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313#section-6) asks to « select a positive integer $e$ as its public exponent ». That allows $e=1$.
- [PKCS#1 v2.0 / RFC 2437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437#section-3.1) states « the public exponent $e$ is an integer between $3$ and $n-1$ satisfying $\gcd(e,\lambda(n))=1$, where $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ ». That does not allow $e=1$, but still allows $e=\lambda(n)+1$ and $e=(p−1)\cdot(q−1)+1$, and perhaps a few other values of $e$ that are such that $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ is the identity function over $[0,n)$ just as it is for $e=1$. [PKCS#1 v2.2](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=7)  has the same prescription for $e$.
- [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61) states « the exponent $e$ shall be an odd positive integer such that $2^{16}<e<2^{256}$ », and that forbids $e=1$. Combined with $d=e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ and a minimum for $d$, that makes it impossible $x\mapsto x^e\bmod n$ is the identity function.

For computer implementations, that depends on if an explicit test against $e=1$ is present or not. Both exist.

Sometime, public keys with $e=1$ or $e=\lambda(n)+1$ (which is more rarely disallowed by software) are used in test keys, or in reverse-engineering, in order to allow easy analysis of padding. Of course, such keys must not be used for encryption or signature of valuable data.

Comment: "$e=\lambda(n)+1$ (which is more rarely disallowed by software)"; actually, some software assumes that $e$ fits in a 32 bit variable; obviously, that would disallow $e=\lambda(n)+1$ (unless $n$ is truly tiny...)

Comment: e=1 means d=1 which is not relatively prime to euler's totient (impossible). (Nor is d then a large integer, 1 is small)
Why do you say this allows e=1? "The original RSA article asks to first choose the private exponent d as « a large, random integer which is relatively prime to (p−1)⋅(q−1) », then to compute e as « the “multiplicative inverse” of d, modulo (p−1)⋅(q−1) ». This makes it extremely improbable that e=1, but allows it."

Comment: @Adrian Self: by the usual definition of that, two integers are relatively prime if their Greatest Common Divisor is $1$. Thus $e=1$ is coprime to Euler's totient $\varphi(n)$. Also, $e=1$ implies $d=1$ only per some definitions of RSA (those that ask $d=e^{-1}\bmodλ(n)$ or $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ ). It implies $d\equiv1\bmodλ(n)$ per all definitions of RSA, and $d\equiv1\bmod\varphi(n)$ per some definition of RSA, but that may not imply $d=1$, and does not under a most usual restriction for $d$, which is $0<d<n$, which thus allows at least $d=\varphi(n)+1$.

Comment: Thanks, brainfart on d!=1, good to know that coprime just means gcd=1

Comment: @poncho: your comment below the answer (made like 30 months ago) led to a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/103713/555) asking an $(n,e)$ pair making textbook RSA encryption the identity over $[0,n)$, yet accepted by a cryptoAPI that checks $e<2^{32}$ (in addition to PKCS#1 conditions), with the less tiny $n$ possible. So far my best is a 244-bit $n$ (that factors in a snap, no contest). Update: this promptly got hugely [improved](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/103717/555)!