# RSA public keys such that encryption is identity

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-generation

In this question, we restrict to RSA public keys $(n,e)$ such that

1. $n$ and $e$ are odd, $3\le e<e_\max$, $e<n$

   Note: For some old Windows API, $e_\max=2^{32}$. In [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=61), $e_\max=2^{256}$. Other requirements are from [PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=6).
2. For all $m\in[0,n)$, it holds $m^e\bmod n=m$. That is, textbook RSA encryption is the identity function. Such unusual requirement is for debugging/analysis purposes.

   Note: That requirement is equivalent to $n$ [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) with $e\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(n)}$, where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

How does the largest possible $n$ evolve as a function of $e_\max$ ?

What's an efficient algorithm to find a $(n,e)$ with large (not necessarily quite maximal) $n$ ?

What are examples (with $n$ as large as possible) for $e_\max=2^{32}$ ?

Do things change if we only require $m^e\bmod n=m$ for *most* $m\in[0,n)$, <strike>that is</strike> *or* remove the requirement that $n$ is square-free?

---

Motivation: an old [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/181277) stated "$n$ is truly tiny" for $e_\max=2^{32}$.

Comment: Does $n$ have to be the product of exactly two prime numbers?

Comment: Heh, I got confused by the title as I thought identity as in identity-management. Fortunately reading the actual question and seeing the author cleared that one up, it's just the identity function $f(x) = x$ or $E(m) = m$ in this case :P

Comment: @Daniel S: no, $n$ is only constrained as in 1. It's not necessary either that it's hard to factor, since the public key is not secure anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks for asking this interesting question, and multiple editorial improvements.

For square-free numbers, condition 2 is equivalent to saying that $\lambda(p)$ divides $e-1$ for every prime $p$ that divides $n$, which in turn says that $(p-1)|(e-1)$ for all primes $p$ that divide $n$ is a necessary and sufficient condition. Given such a condition, a natural approach is to choose $e-1$ with many factors and hope that adding one to each factor is a prime. Given $e$, there will be $d(e-1)$ candidates for prime divisors of $n$ and because factors of $e-1$ occur in pairs, the product of all the $p-1$ values can be at most $(e-1)^{\frac{d(e-1)}2}$. This is an upper bound of sorts on how well we can do, but unlikely to be a very tight one as most of our candidates will not be prime. Heuristically then we might expect a product of $p-1$ around size $(e-1)^{\frac{d(e-1)}{2\log e}}$ and so $n$ of similar size*.

All of this motivates choosing $e$ so that $d(e-1)$ is as large as possible and so we could choose $e-1$ to be a [highly composite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number). Being a little sneakier we might note that odd divisors are of no use to us as they will not be of the form $p-1$. Instead we want to have $e-1$ with a large number of even divisors and so letting $e-1$ be twice a highly composite number is probably slightly better. Being greedy let us choose $(e-1)/2$ to be the largest highly composite number less than $e_{\mathrm max}/2$. In the case of $e_{\mathrm max}=2^{32}$ we can directly look this up in [Ramanujan's classic paper](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram15.pdf) and see that the choice $(e-1)/2=2095133040=2^4\cdot3^4\cdot5\cdot7\cdot 11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19$, which is equivalent to the choice $e=4190266081<2^{32}$. Here's some `sage`

```
eminus1 = 2^5*3^4*5*7*11*13*17*19
pp = []
for d in eminus1.divisors():
    if is_prime(d+1):
        pp+=[d+1]
n = prod(pp)
```

which gives us the 8012-bit $n$ :

```
709646208014585150890871550433345056103596951823588673062275614500185549073757388141231464088281182469964275713741823081119376553744553888460013731836818457690645159749444897904379484735678885208632475222542089843255457586557157192693077597549612572185484270372933578241322991701582270631442897237888777784427046809586941066881187275863715679017344867341317817037488231592067648304962483440201315626634676614628738924360238679010692824875091147023509250598084747598601331851467628158366840414176527562338651574323363308401031464146837204005297508483200802331440182024566132593026280792754339338888418114289205539708802892126128394425942636073747287685556784279959306681795124263894971083243513820403794650572000621494793075790805601475858616359077542210912301801626897849297833516161049824423111801676806714364289101745801280380322417390095474316750444400897514816405976218003382663217392350599466928327002452844913876925180238187923399920000961136382624827296252793015195688029552243938787885559528344199179843462541001024593576810163221575784629820459768138273537191466234350621908012387013092994493323540013809484775566269677490011102097358733314489863307418531090903542906349933666960108764219612093131106865438382095096760945733775450856039034111294965246059070415990133443545231060410567678149466186356755403229078154827586116908234349501396471831302801918478570370845164066724331087136341060318573490792676263276046757692350939135375146554886120263972014539543483319092583452771807359942947767791704652160989733062655300947505983468036469534172433073554329454940958963980366227319614082760795466458602840272493610908746784140775814921226720472012779991619902772009511513876311572756720315505723978897545450318192817346866775711797473562023110590029486954872112538519305855400760952824509365115209842732952503164489403037745409932750773229406460278448112545535678381916473526884142741710615488487242704823690394318376019030450198962361342367514952519293804227906712790708430460369321461239831745682083801098886352914417543364259874119977843065586553402123831629649634020580672862276382210738132451160697129225063413839022967175257339497779135945413194267153918862698526387450871624555589515220480538545102341594782123777187023279295807514420540155994517703363855436579918814137167679702342119373527577732329172386300608769293445615932445746413773715895259229096188705209848008477180405483862978079696493510
```

As fgrieu points out, this is even, as our `sage` code included the divisor 1, so we should divide out by the factor of 2. However, if we drop our square-free assumption, we note that 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19 all divide $n$. If we allow for exceptions in the cases where $p|m$ but $p^r$ does not divide $m$ (here $r$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$), we can increase the power of each of these primes and still have a number whose Carmichael function evaluates to $e-1$. Specifically, we can multiply $n$ by $3^4\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19/2$ to form the a 8037-bit modulus which will fail on a proportion
$$1-\frac{163}{243}\frac{21}{25}\frac{43}{49}\frac{111}{121}\frac{157}{169}\frac{273}{289}\frac{343}{361}$$
of messages.

In the comments below @fgrieu suggests that it would be of interest to find divisors of this $n$ with bit length exactly 2048 or 3072. This can be done straightforwardly enough; we run through our list of primes (I will do this in reverse to reduce the chances of small factors being spotted e.g. because the modulus ends in 5), multiplying in a prime unless it would form a product of too large a bit length. Here's some more `sage`

```
pp.reverse()
n2048 = 1
lg2048 = 2048.0
for p in pp:
    if N(log(p,2.0)) <= lg2048:
        n2048 *=p
        lg2048 -= log(p,2.0)
```

which gives the following 2048-bit modulus for the same value of $e$ :

```
25221518893438748889850305777274652645546562003164475182563355199272942456123642025485356087317855439495470736885864906996264229739957876791659643881508498160047738594439635347685131735361416229325271419313881003841185062233877601616251730435123363625037350695419443692395285844362991144820635808694811600641716706712052066522648145932621369340864581630105199301967963217981369210997982734834265708376111780248393932908864959674389034700872109764453034480103626184828403012997872045576535956627817680079571492181167547222968907316303637488523263623449915880540034149147125803970946660919904134707121646808677077340113
```

In terms of behaviour of the size of $n$ achievable as a function of $e_{\mathbf max}$, Ramanujan proved (see equation 163 of his paper) that the gap between highly composite numbers near $x$ is
$$O\left(\frac{x(\log\log\log x)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\log\log x}}\right)$$
so that we will be able to find an $e$ with $(e-1)/2$ highly composite and $(1-\epsilon)e_{\mathrm max}<e<e_{\mathrm max}$. For such an $e$, $(e-1)$ will have
$$2^{\frac{\log e}{\log\log e}+O\left(\frac{\log e}{(\log\log e)^2}\right)}$$
even divisors (see section II.5 of Ramanujan). The expected penalty for only allowing divisors which are one less than a prime can be absorbed into the error term and we see that
$$\log\log n\sim\log\log e^{d((e-1)/2)}\sim\frac{\log e}{(\log 2)(\log\log e)},$$
so that the size of the largest $n$ is growing almost exponentially in some sense.

Ramanujan's calculated list of highly composite numbers does not extend as far as $2^{256}$, but he did provide a good algorithmic description of how to construct large "superior highly composite" numbers that could furnish candidate $e$ value around that size. Alternatively even straightforward choices such as taking $e$ to be a large factorial/primorial plus one should generate large $n$. If the $e_{\mathrm max}=2^{256}$ is of especial interest, I can probably throw together some `sage`, but I hope that the above answers the question in a somewhat complete manner.

---

(*) - In fact for our choice of $e$ our candidates have a noticeably better chance of being prime than $1/\log e$.

Comment: Nitpick: that 8012-bit $n$ is even, contrary to requirement 1. But $n'=n/2$ (8011-bit) is not, and together with $e=4190266081$ matches all the conditions. Congratulations, AFAIK this is the high score to date. Addition: by trimming this, it would be easy to make a 2048-bit or 3072-bit $n$ that would probably pass the tests of standard CAs and be accepted by most browsers, with possibly unexpected and perhaps useful results.

Comment: Kudos for the 2048-bit $n$, which would pass muster for many CAs and most browsers. Update: with this, we no longer need to consider $e_\max=2^{256}$.